# Deep copy Python with integers vs arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, integer, deep-copy

Given the following code:

```
x = y = z = 0
x = 10
print(y) // prints 0

x = y = z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x[0] = 10
print(y) // prints [10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How come with simple integers Python does not perform a deep copy whilst with arrays it does?

Comment: Nothing is copied in either. Integers are *immutable*.

Comment: Also, if the list behavior is the one you mistook for a deep copy, then you have your concept of "deep copy" completely backward.

Comment: `x[0] = 10` is short for a mutating method call `x.__setitem__(0, 10)`; it's siginificantly different from assigning directly to a name.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Assuming you are new to languages in general, it might be easier to just know that this is the behavior of Python. If you really want to understand why this behavior is the way it is, i recommend using a lower level language or hook up Python to an debugger that shows memory values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you have three pointers pointing to a memory location for an integer. Then you direct one of the pointers, X, to a different memory location. The other two pointers continue to point to the original integer. In the second example, you have three pointers pointing to a list. The list is mutable. Then you change one of the items in the list. The three-pointers are still pointing to the same list and checking the value of  any of them will return the same answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have three *names* bound to the same object. Python's data model doesn't include a notion of memory: that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @chepner I read your article. Nicely explained.